# How do you customize the route after a user logs-in or signs-in in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Currently, a user gets redirected to a root index page after sign-in/log-in but I want to customize it so that the redirect goes to a different page.

My route file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admins'
  root 'home#index'
  get '/' => "courses#index", as: :user_root
  devise_for :users, path: 'users'
    resources :courses, :lessons
end
```

I understand that by default, the root become where the redirect goes to so I used the code `get '/' => "courses#index", as: :user_root`and the redirect worked as I wanted to. However, when a user logs-out, the redirect tries to go to `get '/' => "courses#index", as: :user_root`once again which I do no want. Instead, I want the redirect when a user logs-out to go to `root 'home#index'`.

So essentially my question is how can I customize my root so I can achieve different redirects depending on whether a user logs-in/signs-in and logs-out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
end
```

It is on devise wiki:

[signing in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

[signing out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out)